# ¿Cómo generar un menú dinámico con submenús a partir de un JSON, utilizando jQuery y HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

Estoy trabajando con servicios ***RestFul***, obtengo el *JSON* de los menús y sub-menús en servicios separados pero ligados con su respectivo `id`.

```
$.getJSON( crudServiceBaseUrl + "/menus", function( data ) {

    $.each( data.response.siMenuGral.ttMenus, function( key, val ) {

        //Número de Menús
        var totalMenus = data.response.siMenuGral.ttMenus.length; 

        for (var i=0; i<totalMenus; i++) {
            var menu = val.cMenu;
            $("#menuBase").append(
                '<ul id="menuBase1"><li>'+menu+'<ul><li>Sub Menu</li></ul></li></ul>'
            );
        }
    });
});
```

*JSON* Que obtengo del `data` al consumir el servicio: 'crudServiceBaseUrl + "/menus"'

```
  //Menús del sistema PMS
  "ttMenuGral":
                [
                    {
                        "cSistema": "PMS",
                        "cMenu": "Ama Llaves",
                        "cSubMenu": "",
                        "cOpcion": "",
                        "cPrograma": "",
                        "iSec": 6,
                        "lexiste": false,
                        "cRowID": "0x000000000000048d",
                        "lError": false,
                        "cErrDesc": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "cSistema": "PMS",
                        "cMenu": "Auditoria",
                        "cSubMenu": "",
                        "cOpcion": "",
                        "cPrograma": "",
                        "iSec": 5,
                        "lexiste": false,
                        "cRowID": "0x0000000000000488",
                        "lError": false,
                        "cErrDesc": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "cSistema": "PMS",
                        "cMenu": "Caja",
                        "cSubMenu": "",
                        "cOpcion": "",
                        "cPrograma": "",
                        "iSec": 4,
                        "lexiste": false,
                        "cRowID": "0x000000000000048b",
                        "lError": false,
                        "cErrDesc": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "cSistema": "PMS",
                        "cMenu": "Consultas",
                        "cSubMenu": "",
                        "cOpcion": "",
                        "cPrograma": "",
                        "iSec": 1,
                        "lexiste": false,
                        "cRowID": "0x0000000000000481",
                        "lError": false,
                        "cErrDesc": ""
                    },
                  ]
```

Para obtener el Sub-Menú es necesario enviar como parametro el nombre del menú a mi servicio rest.
El servicio se envia de esta forma: 'crudServiceBaseUrl + "/menus/AmaLlaves"'

Mi `id` en este caso seria el campo cMenu

```
//data que se obtiene al enviar como parametro el menú de "Ama Llaves"

"ttMenuGral":
                [
                    {
                        "cSistema": "PMS",
                        "cMenu": "Ama Llaves",
                        "cSubMenu": "Estado de Cuartos",
                        "cOpcion": "",
                        "cPrograma": "amallaves/estado_cuartos",
                        "iSec": 601,
                        "lexiste": false,
                        "cRowID": "0x000000000000049d",
                        "lError": false,
                        "cErrDesc": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "cSistema": "PMS",
                        "cMenu": "Ama Llaves",
                        "cSubMenu": "Fuera de Orden",
                        "cOpcion": "",
                        "cPrograma": "amallaves/fuera_orden",
                        "iSec": 604,
                        "lexiste": false,
                        "cRowID": "0x000000000000049c",
                        "lError": false,
                        "cErrDesc": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "cSistema": "PMS",
                        "cMenu": "Ama Llaves",
                        "cSubMenu": "Fuera de Servicio",
                        "cOpcion": "",
                        "cPrograma": "amallaves/fuera_servicio",
                        "iSec": 603,
                        "lexiste": false,
                        "cRowID": "0x0000000000000486",
                        "lError": false,
                        "cErrDesc": ""
                    }
                ]
```

Quisiera saber cómo crear el menú con sus correspondientes sub-menús a partir del *JSON* que obtengo.

Comment: Agrega por favor el json que obtienes en `data`, y el json que obtienes al llamar a los submenus.

Comment: Un ejemplo del `JSON` que obtienes ayudaría a entender mejor lo que deseas hacer.

Comment: Espero que con la información que anexe a mi publicación ayude. Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con esto.

```js
var ttMenuGral = [
                    {
                        "cSistema": "PMS",
                        "cMenu": "Ama Llaves",
                        "cSubMenu": "",
                        "cOpcion": "",
                        "cPrograma": "",
                        "iSec": 6,
                        "lexiste": false,
                        "cRowID": "0x000000000000048d",
                        "lError": false,
                        "cErrDesc": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "cSistema": "PMS",
                        "cMenu": "Auditoria",
                        "cSubMenu": "",
                        "cOpcion": "",
                        "cPrograma": "",
                        "iSec": 5,
                        "lexiste": false,
                        "cRowID": "0x0000000000000488",
                        "lError": false,
                        "cErrDesc": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "cSistema": "PMS",
                        "cMenu": "Caja",
                        "cSubMenu": "",
                        "cOpcion": "",
                        "cPrograma": "",
                        "iSec": 4,
                        "lexiste": false,
                        "cRowID": "0x000000000000048b",
                        "lError": false,
                        "cErrDesc": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "cSistema": "PMS",
                        "cMenu": "Consultas",
                        "cSubMenu": "",
                        "cOpcion": "",
                        "cPrograma": "",
                        "iSec": 1,
                        "lexiste": false,
                        "cRowID": "0x0000000000000481",
                        "lError": false,
                        "cErrDesc": ""
                    },
                  ]
subMenuGral=[
                    {
                        "cSistema": "PMS",
                        "cMenu": "Ama Llaves",
                        "cSubMenu": "Estado de Cuartos",
                        "cOpcion": "",
                        "cPrograma": "amallaves/estado_cuartos",
                        "iSec": 601,
                        "lexiste": false,
                        "cRowID": "0x000000000000049d",
                        "lError": false,
                        "cErrDesc": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "cSistema": "PMS",
                        "cMenu": "Ama Llaves",
                        "cSubMenu": "Fuera de Orden",
                        "cOpcion": "",
                        "cPrograma": "amallaves/fuera_orden",
                        "iSec": 604,
                        "lexiste": false,
                        "cRowID": "0x000000000000049c",
                        "lError": false,
                        "cErrDesc": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "cSistema": "PMS",
                        "cMenu": "Ama Llaves",
                        "cSubMenu": "Fuera de Servicio",
                        "cOpcion": "",
                        "cPrograma": "amallaves/fuera_servicio",
                        "iSec": 603,
                        "lexiste": false,
                        "cRowID": "0x0000000000000486",
                        "lError": false,
                        "cErrDesc": ""
                    }
                ]


crearMenu(ttMenuGral);
crearSubMenu(subMenuGral);

function crearMenu(menu){
  console.log(menu)
  for (var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
//pintamos los menus y aca menu le damos de class el menu[i].cMenu,
// para utilizarlo en el momento de agregar el submenu
  var className = menu[i].cMenu.replace(" ","");
    $(".nav").append("<li   class="+className+">"+menu[i].cMenu+"</li>")
}
}

function crearSubMenu(menu){
  for (var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
//obtenemos la class que le dimos en la function pasada para 
//agregar el  submenu
  var className = menu[i].cMenu.replace(" ","");
    if(i == 0){
//agregamos un <ul> el cual va hacer el contenedor del submenu
        $("."+className).append('<ul class="subNav"></ul>')   
    }
//y por ultimo agregamos los item al submenu
    $("."+className +" ul").append("<li   class="+className+">"+menu[i].cSubMenu+"</li>")
}
}
```

```css
ul, li {
    list-style:none;
   }
.nav > li {
    float:left;
  padding:0px 10px;
   }
   
  .nav li ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    min-width:140px;
   }
.nav li:hover > ul {
    display:block !important;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
   <ul class="nav">
      </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Me funciono perfertamente, me base en este programa para crear tambien las opciones de cada sub-menú y corre de maravilla, te agradezco.Saludos!